# Java Nested If condition

Tags: java, nested-if

I suddenly got a strange doubt..

I want to know whether

```
if(a && b) {
}
```

is same as

```
if(a) {
  if(b) {
  }
}
```

or not..

Both the cases giving me the same result. But, I'm still not feeling comfort to use the first method in my project.

Any helps??

Comment: That should work, in my opinion.

Comment: you can add other statements in the outer `if` block outside inner `if` but in the first case both conditions should be true to get inside the `if` block

Answer (score 2):

If using If-else statement then 
if loop will execute only condition is true:---

```
if(condition){
//execute when it is true
}
```

In your case you are using Two variable a and b with AND OPERATOR.
The property of `AND OPERATOR` is If All giving value is true then it will return true otherwise false.

If you want to use your method then

```
/*
check for your in a and b
both are true
*/
 then your method will be execdute

 if(a && b) {
 //if a and b both return true(a=true,b=true)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are the same as far as functionality is concerned. `&&` is a short-circuit operator. So, in `a && b`, `b` will be evaluated only if `a` is evaluated to `true`.

Same is the case with *nested `if`*. The *inner `if`* will be executed only when *outer `if`* is evaluated to `true`. But the 1<sup>st</sup> one shows your intents better if you want to execute the code only when both `a` and `b` are `true`.

But, one difference is that, you can implement the functionality of `a = true`, `b = false`, in 2<sup>nd</sup> case by adding that functionality before the *nested `if`* starts. But, you can't do that in 1<sup>st</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It is same. In the first case compiler guarantees that second condition will not be executed if first condition returns false.

Answer (score 0):

`a && b` means if `a` is tue and so is `b`, so:

```
if(a && b) {
}
```

does not leave space for indecision, it's all or nothing, only if `a && b` the if body will be executed, while

```
if(a) {
  if(b) {
  }
}
```

leaves you space to act if `a`, without considering `b` for the moment. So if you want to do some actions before checking `b` you can.

If you do not have anything to do just when `a` then the two are equal and imho the first is to prefer because it is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Both conditions are same as in first one: `if(a && b){  }`, you are checking with `&&` operator  So, in `a && b`, `b` will be evaluated only if `a` is evaluated to true.

while in second case, first of all it will check value of `a` in outer if condition and if it satisfies then it will check value of `b` in inner if condition.

But fist one is more preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's the same thing. The `&&` operator checks if both conditions are true. If you nest your `if` statements like that, it amounts to the same thing since the second one will only be checked if the first one is true. Only separate them if you need something done that involves `a` being true but not `b`.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases  It's just [short-circuiting.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

> in which the second argument is only executed or evaluated if the first argument does not suffice to determine the value of the expression:

*The short-circuit expression x Sand y (using Sand to denote the short-circuit variety) is equivalent to the conditional expression if x then y else false; the expression x Sor y is equivalent to if x then true else y.*

Coming to the syntax,The first thing (`if(a && b)` )which beautifies your code and and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

As many have stated before me: they are technically equivalent (right down to the short-circuit semantics).

But I dare say the && operator is preferred in *any* situation, and that it's not just a matter of taste. The nested if is harder to read in day-to-day code with more than just control statements, and leaves more room for error.

Mostly because `if(b)` communicates:  *"the following block is only executed if **b** is true".*

But that's not what happens! *The block is only executed if **a and b** are true* (which is exactly what the first method communicates rather elegantly). It's very easy to unintentionally pull it out of the `if(a)` context (any IDE has plenty of ways to shuffle code around) and create a bug.

The nested if also leaves a lot of room for horrible code later on. Wedging code between the inner and outer can make it tricky to understand which code is executed when - especially if a and b are complex expressions. And things become *really* nasty when somebody decides to toss in a few else-statements.. :-) There's simply no way to get into that mess with a single && operator.

Some might argue this "flexibility" is a reason to use the second method, but I'd argue there is almost always a way to rewrite that cleanly using explicit conditions. Coding is hard enough without spending all your brain cycles on control logic.

Bottom line: every Java programmer understands the semantics of the conditional-AND operator. Relying on built-in language constructs instead of rolling your own equivalents goes a long way towards maintainability and correctness.

Hope this helps.